# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, null

I'm getting the following error

> "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()"

when I execute following command.

```
 return objDB.Employees.ToList();
```

kindly someone advice me, permanent solution of "how to get null fields from DB using LINQ.

I got this error, when there is atleast one field is null.

thanks

I'm doing this in BLAZOR.

```
public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            try
            {
                return objDB.Employees.ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which field is `null` in the database, and what property on an `Employee` does it correspond to?

Comment: yeah it's annoying trying to find this out